# Array does not wipe

Tags: powershell

I don't understand why my $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers array doesn't wipe every time the function recurses. I don't want it to wipe. Its actually doing what I want it to do right now, which is keep an accurate growing list. I just don't understand why the contents of the array don't wipe every time the function is called. Any help understanding?

```
function Get-GroupMembers {
    Param($Group)
    [System.Collections.ArrayList] $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers = @()
    
    $GroupMembersArray = gam print group-members group $Group | ConvertFrom-Csv
    
    foreach ($GroupMember in $GroupMembersArray) {
        $GroupMemberType = ($GroupMember.type)
        $GroupMemberEmail = ($GroupMember.email)
        $GroupMemberIsAGroup = ($GroupMemberType -eq "GROUP")

            $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers.Add($GroupMember) | Out-Null
            
            if($GroupMemberIsAGroup) {
                     Get-GroupMembers $GroupMemberEmail
                 }
    }
    
    $ReturnedGroupMembers = @{
        "all" = $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers
    }

    Return $ReturnedGroupMembers
}
```

Comment: It should and it does. At least that's what happens when I try to reproduce your example. What makes you think it doesn't?

Comment: Computer will only do what they are told. How did you determine it was not? What is this [$GroupMembersArray = gam print group-members group $Group | ConvertFrom-Csv], specifically 'gam'? That is not native to PowerShell. Is this custom aliased function or other 3rdP aliased cmdlet?

Comment: OK so it turns out the $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers array DOES wipe. I took for granted that it did not because $ReturnedGroupMembers.all gives me all of the data I want, as though the $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers array does not wipe. Any idea why $ReturnedGroupMembers.all gives me the cumulative fetch data, instead of always reflecting the wiped $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers array? It is a scope thing due to recursion?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you are after...

```
function Get-GroupMembers 
{
    Param($Group)
    [System.Collections.ArrayList] $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers = @()

    $GroupMembersArray = Get-LocalGroupMember -Group $Group
      
    foreach ($GroupMember in $GroupMembersArray) {
        $GroupMemberType = ($GroupMember.type)
        $GroupMemberEmail = ($GroupMember.email)
        $GroupMemberIsAGroup = ($GroupMemberType -eq "GROUP")

            $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers.Add($GroupMember) | Out-Null
            
            if($GroupMemberIsAGroup) {
                     Get-GroupMembers $GroupMemberEmail
                 }
    }
    
    $ReturnedGroupMembers = @{
        "all" = $ReturnedAnyTypeMembers
    }

    Return $ReturnedGroupMembers
}

'Administrators','Users' | 
ForEach-Object {Get-GroupMembers -Group $PSItem} | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

# Results
<#
Name Value                                                              
---- -----                                                              
all  {104DB2FE-76B8-4\Administrator, 104DB2FE-76B8-4\WDAGUtilityAccount}
all  {NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users, NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE}                                                           
#>
```

... or something else?